# Как задать единый css style постам в wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой, использую тему **Basic**, как только публикую запись, она выходит под `class = "post2213"` и т.д., каждый пост под своим классом. Как задать всем постам, чтобы они выходили в одном стиле?

Comment: Зачем? Это **дополнительный** класс для гибкости назначения стилей конкретным постам. Просто не используй его и всё. Какие проблемы?

Comment: Мне и нужно, просто, сделать, 1 стиль для новых записей, чтобы всегда были с одним css, я не хочу возиться и колупаться, а в коде видеть подобное class post 112312 3psd iAd soadp aspdi pasd, требуется просто, пост и class = "post" и ВСЕ, БЕЗ ВСЯКОГО МУСОРА И ЛИШНЕГО ГЕМОРРОЯ!

Comment: Я находил почти решение на англ ресурсах, там в файле post_template следовало заменить функцию постинга, в данный момент он генерирует рандомное значение post2131 post139213 и тд, а нужно сделать просто post

Comment: У тебя и так есть единый стиль для всех постов. Ничего делать не надо. ВООБЩЕ. А что до геммороя - так ты сам его ищешь и создаёшь. И себе и другим.

Comment: Единого стиля не может не быть, тк даже без  style его можно задать по html-тегам. Но в этой теме, как и в любой другой нормальной стилей до чёртиков. https://i.imgur.com/eH39Cee.jpeg. А если ты не знаешь css - это совершено другой вопрос.

Comment: Вот ты мне скрин скинул, как мне тогда просто скажи сделать, чтобы все посты которые публиковались, были по 1 стилю! Я даю новую запись и она публикуется по моим css данным, где это сделать!

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Задавай его отдельно согласно правилам SO. А вообще они и так одного стиля. Если ты ничего не ломал.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы действительно используете тему [Basic](https://wordpress.org/support/theme/basic/), то ответ на ваш вопрос короткий: необходимое вам поведение работает из коробки:
[image: страница Wordpress-сайта с темой Basic]

Если у вас отсутствуют классы "post" и другие, соответствующие выводимой записи, то либо в своём вопросе вы указали неправильное название темы, либо установили какие-то плагины, меняющие набор классов у каждой выводимой записи

Если тема всё же указана верно и классы на самом деле на месте, а вам нужно добавить свой стиль записям, но вы не хотите создавать дочернюю тему, то идёте в админке в раздел Внешний вид -> Настроить -> Пользовательский код -> CSS стили.

И пишите там свои стили, применяемые к необходимому классу

Answer (score 1):

Человек в ответе, написал корректно. **Желательно** через хук добавить свой класс, но есть и другое решение. Проверять начало имени стиля.

```
div[class^="post"]{
font-size: 18px;
...
}
```

Если Вам надо убрать базовый, то в шаблоне ищите нечто похожее:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

И заменяете на свой класс.

Либо вешаете фильтр

```
add_filter('post_class', 'my_class');
function my_class($classes) {
global $post;
    $new_classes = array();
    $new_classes[] = 'my_post';
    return new_classes;
}
```

Comment: Слов "хук" и "желательно" в его ответе нет, не додумывайте. Что там в теме - неизвестно, есть ли в ней какие-то хуки. Поэтому ваш ответ предпочтителен.

Comment: Вы наверное не понимаете, что требуется. Есть файл post-template.php. В нем есть строчка кода, которая отвечает за функцию постинга записей, все записи идут с определенным class'ом, который не является единым. Я не понимаю код, но мне нужна помощь, чтобы ИМЕННО В php, один раз задался шаблон, чтобы при постинге новой записи ему присваивался сразу class мой со всеми данными, которые я внесу этому классу в файле style.

Comment: Молодой человек, менять основной стиль - не правильно. Это внутренний механизм WordPress, который позволяет уникальным образом задавать стили для разных постов. У Вас есть по кодексу 2 способа. Первый: через хук добавить свой стиль, Второй: использовать стиль начинающийся class^="post", остальное всё не рекомендуется, хотя если хочется, то можно через тот же хук классов, удалять из массива имя пост[номер] и добавлять свой (ответ обновил)... Но в этом случае возможны проблемы со стандартным функционалом.

Comment: В файле, который Вы указали,  есть фильтр $classes = apply_filters( 'post_class', $classes, $class, $post->ID ); Вот и пропишите add_filter('post_class', 'my_class'); где функция my_class очистит все не нужные классы из массива (по вашим условиям) и добавит те классы, что надо, если не подходит всё то, что рекомендуется выше.

Comment: У меня не получается ничего, что я делаю не так? Все равно посты создаются с post12131 цифрами.

Answer (score 0):

Ладно ребята, я супер тупой, но всем спасибо за помощь)))
Оказывается я через админку все время пытался css классу что-либо задать и не работало(в админке настройка шаблона), но только я додумался зайти в style.css файл самого проекта через корневую систему на компе, так все заработало))) оказывается просто нужно было реал .post {} и все работает, а внутри вордпресса вообще ничего не работало я хз почему, может кому тоже в будущем пригодится! тут больше инфы, как определенным постам менять стили https://wp-kama.ru/function/post_class.

Comment: Не смешно. Это же базовые знания, которые необходимо знать. Это как с какой стороны брать в руки нож или топор. Тебе же Конкретно писали, что сделать, так ты не вникал и до сих пор не стой стороны заходишь к корове. Тебе конкретные пример написали с использованием post_class, а ты как откровение выдаешь это за свою гениальность... Не хорошо.

Comment: facepalm, базовых знаний хватало, я знал что нужно было задавать классу пост, но у меня не работало ничего, а поэтому я устал уже подбирать комбинации и как чего там делать и хотел лишь снести все это под 1 стиль, думал так заработает. Но нет, увы, ошибка была лишь в вордпрессе, через его редактор все менялось, но не работалось(даж Кеш скидывал и тд, без пользы какой-либо). Только зашел в файл style.css в файлах и изменил там, как все заработало.

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте свой собственный класс:

```
class="post2213 my_own_awesome_class"
```

И тогда сможете назначить общие стили для всех постов. Например, css:

```
.my_own_awesome_class { font-size: 18px; }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно перейдя по ссылке [edit].

Comment: Это не совсем то, мне не нужно каждый раз добавлять класс или еще что-то, мне надо из php кода изменить структуру подачи поста, чтобы он изначально уже просто шел с классом post, без цифр и прочего.